# Neural Network training error stochastic gradient descent

Tags: python, neural-network, gradient-descent

I have this implementation of a feed forward neural network with stochastic gradient descent in python. When training a NN instance with the xor gate, it trains just fine. But when I train the instance with stock change data, it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\predict\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    stock.train(stockData, 30, 10, 3.0)
  File "F:\predict\network.py", line 46, in train
    self.updateMiniBatch(miniBatch, eta)
  File "F:\predict\network.py", line 62, in updateMiniBatch
    delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backPropagate(x, y)
  File "F:\predict\network.py", line 102, in backPropagate
    nabla_w[-l] = numpy.dot(delta, activations[-l - 1].transpose())
ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

The XOR Gate data, and stock data looks as such (Mind you the stock data has been truncated greatly):

```
xorData = [
    ([0, 0], [0]),
    ([0, 1], [1]),
    ([1, 0], [1]),
    ([1, 1], [0])
]

stockData = [
    ([0.0, 0.0, 0.003927144694969353], [-0.0038780602954071597]), 
    ([0.0, 0.003927144694969353, -0.0038780602954071597], [0.0012018010088359343]),
    ([0.003927144694969353, -0.0038780602954071597, 0.0012018010088359343], [-0.0115302033846727])
]
```

I then create a network with 2 inputs, 2 hidden, and 1 output for the XOR Gate. And 3 inputs, 15 hidden, and 1 output for the Stock data.

```
xor = network.NN([2, 2, 1])
xor.train(xorData, 30, 10, 3.0)

stock = network.NN([3, 15, 1])
stock.train(stockData, 30, 10, 3.0)
```

Both of the training sets have the exact same structure, so why would this error occur?

network.py:

```
import numpy
import random
import json

# the sigmoid function
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + numpy.exp(-z))

# the derivative of the sigmoid function
def sigmoidPrime(z):
    return sigmoid(z) * (1 - sigmoid(z))

# sigmoid vectors
sigmoidVector = numpy.vectorize(sigmoid)
sigmoidPrimeVector = numpy.vectorize(sigmoidPrime)

#A class that implements stochastic gradient descent learning algorithm for a feedforward neural network
class NN:
    def __init__(self, sizes):
        self.numLayers = len(sizes)
        self.sizes = sizes

        # the biases and weights for the network are initialized randomly, using a Guassian distribution with mean 0, and variance 1
        self.biases = [numpy.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
        self.weights = [numpy.random.randn(y, x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

    # feedForward function - return the output of the network
    def feedForward(self, inputs):
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            inputs = sigmoidVector(numpy.dot(w, inputs) + b)
        return inputs

    # train function - train the neural network using mini-batch stochastic gradient descent
    # the trainingData is a list of tuples "(x, y)" representing the training inputs and the desired outputs
    # if testData is provided then the network will be evaluated against the test data after each epoch
    def train(self, trainingData, epochs, miniBatchSize, eta, testData = None):
        if testData:
            nTest = len(testData)

        n = len(trainingData)
        for j in xrange(epochs):
            random.shuffle(trainingData)

            miniBatches = [trainingData[k:k + miniBatchSize] for k in xrange(0, n, miniBatchSize)]
            for miniBatch in miniBatches:
                self.updateMiniBatch(miniBatch, eta)

            if testData:
                print "Epoch %i: %i / %i" % (j, self.evaluate(testData), nTest)
            else:
                print "Epoch %i complete" % j


    # updateMiniBatch function - update the network's weights and biases by applying gradient descent using backpropagation
    # to a single mini batch
    # the miniBatch is a list of tuples "(x, y)" and eta is the learning rate
    def updateMiniBatch(self, miniBatch, eta):
        nabla_b = [numpy.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
        nabla_w = [numpy.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]

        for x, y in miniBatch:
            delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backPropagate(x, y)

            nabla_b = [nb + dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
            nabla_w = [nw + dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]

        self.weights = [w - (eta / len(miniBatch)) * nw for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
        self.biases = [b - (eta / len(miniBatch)) * nb for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]

    # backPropagate function - returns a tuple "(nabla_b, nabla_w)" representing the gradient for the cost function C_x
    # nabla_b and nabla_w are layer-by-layer lists of numpy arrays, similar to self.biases and self.weights
    def backPropagate(self, x, y):
        nabla_b = [numpy.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
        nabla_w = [numpy.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]

        x = numpy.array(x)
        y = numpy.array(y)

        # feedForward
        activation = x
        activations = [x] # list to store all of the activations, layer by layer
        zs = [] # list to store all of the z vectors, layer by layer

        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            z = numpy.dot(w, activation) + b
            zs.append(z)

            activation = sigmoidVector(z)
            activations.append(activation)

        # backward pass
        delta = self.costDerivative(activations[-1], y) * sigmoidPrimeVector(zs[-1])
        nabla_b[-1] = delta
        nabla_w[-1] = numpy.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())

        for l in xrange(2, self.numLayers):
            spv = sigmoidPrimeVector(zs[-l])

            delta = numpy.dot(self.weights[-l + 1].transpose(), delta) * spv

            nabla_b[-l] = delta
            nabla_w[-l] = numpy.dot(delta, activations[-l - 1].transpose())

        return (nabla_b, nabla_w)

    # evaluate function - return the number of test inputs for which the neural network outputs the correct result
    def evaluate(self, testData):
        testResults = [(numpy.argmax(self.feedForward(x)), y) for (x, y) in testData]
        return sum(int(x == y) for (x, y) in testResults)

    # costDerivative function - return the vector of partial derivatives for the output activations
    def costDerivative(self, outputActivations, y):
        return (outputActivations - y)

    # save function - save the neural network to filename
    def save(self, filename):
        data = {
            "sizes": self.sizes,
            "weights": [w.tolist() for w in self.weights],
            "biases": [b.tolist() for b in self.biases]
        }

        with open(filename, "w") as handle:
            json.dump(data, handle)

# load function - load a neural network from the file filename
# returns a network instance
def load(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as handle:
        data = json.load(handle)

    network = NN(data["sizes"])
    network.weights = [numpy.array(w) for w in data["weights"]]
    network.biases = [numpy.array(b) for b in data["biases"]]

    return network
```

**EDIT:**
I believe it might have something to do with the hidden layer value. I changed the XOR Gate hidden layer number and it threw the same error. It seems as if the hidden layer value must be the exact same as the amount for the input layer.

Comment: The hidden layer doesn't necessarily have to have the same number of nodes as the input layer. Just ensure that each input layer node has a "synapse" that goes into each hidden-layer node.

Comment: I understand that conceptually and all. I know there is something wrong with the implementation though, which is what I'm trying to figure out.